# Getting Header into file using ISAPI Filter

Tags: c++, isapi

I am trying to get the entire raw header into a file but everytime I attempt to write the contents I get a file full of ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ. What am I doing wrong?

```
DWORD CTryISAPIFilter::OnPreprocHeaders(CHttpFilterContext* httpContext,
    PHTTP_FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS headerInformation)
{


    char buffer[4096];
    DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);

    BOOL HeaderBoolean = headerInformation->GetHeader(httpContext->m_pFC, "ALL_RAW", buffer, &bufferSize); 
    char * ptrIn = (char *) buffer;
    std::string postData2 = ptrIn;
    char * outputString = new char[4096];

    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<4096;i++){
        outputString[i] = postData2[i];
    }
    outputString[i+1] = NULL;


    std::ofstream outfile ("D:\\WebSites\\wwwroot\\test.txt",std::ios::app);

    outfile << outputString << std::endl;

    outfile.close(); 
    return SF_STATUS_REQ_NEXT_NOTIFICATION;
}
```

Comment: You do realize that `outputString[i+1] = NULL;` results in a bit of buffer overrun, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `headerInformation->GetHeader()` returning success?

If so, how much is it actually writing into `buffer` (presumably it tells you this in a value it places in `bufferSize`)

I suspect that `GetHeader()` is failing, and nothing is being written to `buffer` because:

- you're getting all "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ" characters (which is what the debug builds of VC will set uninitialized memory to), and
- you're not getting an exception thrown when you index `postData2` well past what should usually be the end of the string (in most cases anyway). So there's apparently no '\0' terminator in `buffer` (which `GetHeader()` will write if it succeeds).

You need to check for this failure and examine `GetLastError()` to get more information on what the failure is.

Update: Your buffer might not be large enough.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163939.aspx for how to appropriately size the buffer.

Update 2: It's been a while since I've done web stuff, but isn't "ALL_RAW" a CGI-style server environment variable rather than a header?  Shouldn't you retrieve this using `GetServerVariable()` instead of `GetHeader()`?

Comment: So I think you are right, based on the MS Documentation the data may not be available at the time I am trying to pull it. I am able to pull say URL variable though. I will try GetServerVariables but I don't think I will have much luck. Thanks anyways.